# How do I hide or show content with CSS depending on screen size?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ionic-framework, ionic3, bootstrap-4

Just like Bootstrap, Ionic (Ionic 3) lets us resize the width of a column based on screen size using `col-sm-8`, `col-md-6`, `col-lg-4`. Bootstrap also comes with classes like `visible-xs`, `hidden-sm`, etc. that enables us to show or hide content according to the screen size. Does Ionic 3 ship with anything that lets us do the same?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I copied the following CSS classes from Bootstrap 4 Alpha into my project and they work perfectly.

```
.invisible {
  visibility: hidden !important;
}

.hidden-xs-up {
  display: none !important;
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .hidden-xs-down {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .hidden-sm-up {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .hidden-sm-down {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .hidden-md-up {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .hidden-md-down {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .hidden-lg-up {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1199px) {
  .hidden-lg-down {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .hidden-xl-up {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

.hidden-xl-down {
  display: none !important;
}
```

**`Docs`:**
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/

Answer (score 4):

Example:

```
<div hidden-xs visible-block-md>Hidden on small screen</div>
```

A SCSS solution would be:

```
$screen-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 576px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px
) !default;

@each $keySize, $valueSize in $screen-breakpoints {
    [hidden-#{$keySize}] {
        @media (min-width: $valueSize) {
            display: none;
        }
    }
}

@each $keySize, $valueSize in $screen-breakpoints {
    [visible-block-#{$keySize}] {
        @media (min-width: $valueSize) {
            display: block;
        }
    }
}

@each $keySize, $valueSize in $screen-breakpoints {
    [visible-inline-block-#{$keySize}] {
        @media (min-width: $valueSize) {
            display: inline-block;
        }
    }
}
```

If you're using Ionic you could go with something like:

```
@each $breakpoint in map-keys($screen-breakpoints) {
    $infix: breakpoint-infix($breakpoint, $screen-breakpoints);

    @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint, $screen-breakpoints) {
        // Provide `[hidden-{bp}]` attributes for floating the element based
        // on the breakpoint
        [hidden#{$infix}] {
            display: none !important;
        }
    }
}
```