# Restricting a SwitchPreference only for mobile device

Tags: android, ionic3, ionic-native

I'm working with ionic/cordova for developing cross-platform apps with angular 5. Everything is working great. I just encountered a scenario where I need to show some preference only on the mobile device. They should not be visible on tablet etc. Is there any way through which I can restrict some of my preferences only to mobile devices ? e.g. some kind of key on the preference to tell it should only be rendered is device is a mobile handset.

I've already googled it but found nothing. Just wondering is there any way or is this thing impossible.

(Remember, its not a bug or issue, I just want some additional functionality in my existing app so asking for code is useless ;) )

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hmm do I understand this right: You want to be able to decide if the device is a smartphone or a tablet? You're not asking about hiding some stuff on a smaller display? Like asked in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44514556/how-do-i-hide-or-show-content-depending-on-screen-size)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Platform service to check whether a device is a mobile phone or a tablet. Using this info, you can set your app preferences as needed. See this slightly modified example from the docs [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/#is) and [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-preferences/):

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AppPreferences } from '@ionic-native/app-preferences';

@Component({...})
export MyPage {
  constructor(public plt: Platform, public appPreferences: AppPreferences) {
    if (this.plt.is('mobile')) {
      this.appPreferences.store(ok, fail, 'key', 'value');
    }
  }
}
```

`ok` and `fail` are the callbacks executed if storing the preferences went well or failed. See the example [here](https://github.com/apla/me.apla.cordova.app-preferences#synopsis).

Comment: Thanks for you answer, really appreciate it. yes I can check which platform I'm on through platform services but what I want is to set "App preferences" based on devices i.e. is it a mobile or tablet. Let me know if you need more clarification on what apppreferences.xml is.

Comment: Alright. Do you mean something like `if (this.plt.is('mobile')) {
      this.appPreferences.store(...)
    }
  }`

Comment: ahh yes. Can you please update your answer with this or refer me to the docs ? Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer and also refered to the docs here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-preferences/